# Create a doc, then update a document using doc in client. Unsure best practice

Tags: mongoose

My aim is to:
1. Create a document -  I need to ensure the document is valid and actually saves to the database as its _id is potentially embedded other docs in the same collection.
2. Once its saved I need to run this document against all other docs in the collection to find which docs _id are embedded in itself.
3. I then want to update this document and save it.

I have been looking round the docs for hours.

I understand that when I edit a saved or fetched document mongoose sees the change and fires updateOne() 
`Mongoose documents track changes. You can modify a document using vanilla JavaScript assignments and Mongoose will convert it into MongoDB update operators.`

Issue 1 is that updateOne() firing on an object is async and if I run bulk doc creation I get a VersionError warning. Is there a way to make this async/await?

The other option is to run updateOne() manually. BUT the docs state that save() is the correct way updates should be done. I cant find a best practice for this. 
`The save() function is generally the right way to update a document with Mongoose. With save(), you get full validation and middleware.`

How do I retrieve and edit a document without firing the standard updateOne() when editing the doc?

Attempt 1

```
    // check if already exists
    const existsCheck = await getCard(null, card.name);
    if (existsCheck) {
      throw new Error(`Duplicate item, ${existsCheck.name} already exists: [${existsCheck.id}]`);
    }

    console.log(`Creating card ${card.name}`);
    const baseCard = new Card( card );

    baseCard.synergiespre = stringToArray(baseCard.synergiespre, ',');
    baseCard.antisynergiespre = stringToArray(baseCard.antisynergiespre, ',');
    // baseCard.markModified('synergiespre');
    // baseCard.markModified('antisynergiespre');
    // create card to:
    // 1. Get an id
    // 2. Ensure save() occurs before creating item synergies editing other item synergies
    await baseCard.save();

    const updatedCardData = await compileSynergiesAndAntiSynergies(baseCard);
    baseCard.synergies = await updatedCardData.synergies; // doesnt await
    baseCard.antisynergies = await updatedCardData.antisynergies; // doesnt await

    const returnPopulatedCard = await getCard(baseCard.id);
    console.log('Populated Return');
    console.log(returnPopulatedCard);

    return returnPopulatedCard;
```

Without await I get VersionError as there are alot of async changes

Attempt 2

```
    // check if already exists
    const existsCheck = await getCard(null, card.name);
    if (existsCheck) {
      throw new Error(`Duplicate item, ${existsCheck.name} already exists: [${existsCheck.id}]`);
    }

    console.log(`Creating card ${card.name}`);
    let baseCard = new Card( card );

    baseCard.synergiespre = stringToArray(baseCard.synergiespre, ',');
    baseCard.antisynergiespre = stringToArray(baseCard.antisynergiespre, ',');
    // baseCard.markModified('synergiespre');
    // baseCard.markModified('antisynergiespre');
    // create card to:
    // 1. Get an id
    // 2. Ensure save() occurs before creating item synergies and editing other item synergies
    baseCard = await baseCard.save();

    const updatedCardData = await compileSynergiesAndAntiSynergies(baseCard);
    baseCard.synergies = await updatedCardData.synergies;
    baseCard.antisynergies = await updatedCardData.antisynergies;
    baseCard = await baseCard.save();

    const returnPopulatedCard = await getCard(baseCard.id);
    console.log('Populated Return');
    console.log(returnPopulatedCard);

    return returnPopulatedCard;
```

VersionError as I trying to save() as recommended. How should I get a doc and edit and then save() without firing updateOne()

Debug Log

```
Mongoose: 
  cards.updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectId("5cfef0ad6037ee55f17d4ee5"), __v: 0 },
    { '$set': {
      antisynergies: [ ObjectId("5cfeea1840b4cc558e14a221") ], 
      synergies: [ 
        ObjectId("5cfeea0e40b4cc558e149e90"),
        ObjectId("5cfeea1040b4cc558e149ed6"),
        ObjectId("5cfeea1040b4cc558e149ee1"), 
        ObjectId("5cfeea1440b4cc558e14a07f"), 
        ObjectId("5cfeea1540b4cc558e14a0bc"), 
        ObjectId("5cfeea1540b4cc558e14a0cf"), 
        ObjectId("5cfef0ad6037ee55f17d4ee5") ],
      updatedAt: new Date("Tue, 11 Jun 2019 00:07:10 GMT") },
      '$inc': { __v: 1 } }, { session: null })
```

ERROR

````
{ VersionError: No matching document found for id "5cfef0ad6037ee55f17d4ee5" version 0 modifiedPaths "synergies, antisynergies"
    at VersionError.MongooseError [as constructor] (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mlgserver/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:14:11)
    at new VersionError (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mlgserver/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/version.js:18:17)
    at generateVersionError (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mlgserver/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:401:10)
    at model.Model.save (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mlgserver/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:459:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mlgserver/dist/mongoose/spirespy/cards.js:416:39)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mlgserver/dist/mongoose/spirespy/cards.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
  message: 'No matching document found for id "5cfef0ad6037ee55f17d4ee5" version 0 modifiedPaths "synergies, antisynergies"',
  name: 'VersionError',
  version: 0,
  modifiedPaths: [ 'synergies', 'antisynergies' ] }```
````

Comment: What is `await updatedCardData.synergies`? How are you awaiting this when there is no function call? Is `updatedCardData.synergies` a function?

Comment: It is nothing. I want to await this hook (updateOne()) that fires when a change is made to the document.